# Property does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) Typescript Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextui

I am using Typescript with React and trying to populate the value for input (@nextui-org/react) , But I am getting the error as below, Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

The data is defined as below and contains json key with name, the object for data is very big and dynamic.

```
const [data, setData] = useState("");
```

[image]

Comment: You have defined the initial state as an empty string. So Typescript will infer that the data type of your `data` state is `string`. So when you do `data[0]`, using square bracket array notation for strings returns the character at that index, in this case the first character of `data`. Now characters are the same as strings in Javascript, so `data[0]` is actually a `string`. As a result, you're trying to access the `.name` property of a `string`, but that's not a native property of a Javascript string. You need to define your state data type explicitly, or use `any`

Comment: @Jayce444 - I tried doing that,  const [data, setData] = useState(any); but getting error as "'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)"

Comment: That's not how Typescript (TS) works, best to review the basics of TS and TS in React. You use angle brackets to specify type, e.g. you can do it like this `useState<any>()`